# How to pass raw string of the content-type x-www-form-urlencoded in retrofit?

Tags: android, json, urlencode, retrofit2, android-webservice

```
     OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request.Builder requestBuilder = chain.request().newBuilder();
     requestBuilder.header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   requestBuilder.header("Accept", "text/json");
  requestBuilder.header("Authorization","Basic fh73hf78fhhf7at");     }).build();

 Retrofit retrofit = new    Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).client(client).addConverterFactory(GsonConv   erterFactory.create()).build();
    BetaAPI betaAPI = retrofit.create(BetaAPI.class);
```

So in interface of retrofit
(params is of the type, "username=david&password=test123&scope=openid+email")

```
  @POST("core/connect/userinfo")
   Call<ResponseBody> getLogin(@Body String params);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("core/connect/userinfo")
Call<ResponseBody> getLogin(@Field("username") String username,@Field("password") String password, @Field("scope") String scope);
```

or use fieldMap annotation

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("core/connect/userinfo")
Call<ResponseBody> getLogin(@FieldMap(encoded = true) Map<String, String> params);
```

Comment: This is not the way to do it. The above mentioned method doesn't work.

Comment: you can refer the official documentation - http://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/